# Return nested type parameter from method of generic class?

Tags: java

How can I get the type of the type parameter of the class or the (same) type parameter of a List instance variable of the class?

```java
public class HasList<T> {
    private List<T> list;

    public ? getType() {
        return // ??
    }

}
```

I think normally types are represented by `Class<?>`, e.g. via the `.class` property, but there might be a better way to represent them in order to solve this question well.

```java
var hasListString = HasList<String>();
var hasListInteger = HasList<Integer>();
hasListString.getType() // -> something representing the String type
hasListInteger.getType() // -> something representing the Integer type
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get generic type of class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime)

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Worth looking into Kotlin's reified generic type that attempts to solve this issue.

Comment: @m0skit0 what if the class' own method doesn't have to do it? Can a consumer of a `List<HasList<?>>` figure out what each `HasList`'s type is?

Comment: Generic types exist only during compilation for the compiler to check but not at runtime (it's basically a `List<Object>` or actually a simple `List` at that point). So there's no way to return a type in this way. The type is kept for reflection purposes if you have a subclass of a generic class which is what e.g. https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html does. The other way to do that is to explicitly require a type / class in the constructor so you can return that (`HasList<String>(String.class)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this in a way that supports all `T`, including generic types, you need to use something like a type token.

For example, Guava has [`TypeToken`](https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html), which is an abstract class that you have to subclass in order to get an instance of it:

```
TypeToken<String> stringTypeToken = new TypeToken<String>() {};
TypeToken<Integer> integerTypeToken = new TypeToken<Integer>() {};
TypeToken<List<String>> listOfStringTypeToken = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {};
```

The `{}` is important here: it's creating an instance of an anonymous class, which is a subclass of `TypeToken`.

You can pass a `TypeToken` into the constructor of your `HasList` class, and return it from the getter.

---

Of course, you may not want to take a dependency on an external library for this; it's not hard to implement something similar yourself:

```
public abstract class HasList<T> {
  // ...

  public Type getType() {
    Type type = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    ParameterizedType paramType = (ParameterizedType) type;
    return paramType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: I love `TypeToken`, but it’s just messy if the types youre passing dont take class parameter(s). IMO the best solution is overloading and giving the option to pass a `Class<T>` or  `TypeToken` (or something similar  to TypeToken)

Answer (score 2):

Due to [type erasure](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure#1-class-type-erasure) you couldn't get that type in runtime.
If `T` is not a generic itself, typical workaround works: demand class object at the constructor:

```
public class HasList<T> {
    private final Class<T> type;
    private List<T> list;

    public HasList(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Class<T> getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works provided `T` is not itself generic.